# ¿Como ejecutar una acción solo cuando la variable "Cookie" exista?

Tags: php

Lo que yo intento hacer es que se me muestre un menú con la opción "Panel de Control" solo si el usuario a iniciado sesion, en caso de que el usuario no tenga ninguna sesion iniciada, se mostrara el mismo menú, solo que sin la opción "Panel de control"

Este es mi código, a decir verdad no tengo muy claro si la instrucción `isset` pueda hacer lo que yo quiero...

El problema esta en que al ejecutar el programa, me dice `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean`

Codigo:

```
<?php 
include ("conecta.php");
if (isset ($_COOKIE['MiGalleta'])){ 
    $nombre = $_COOKIE['MiGalleta'];
    $sql = "SELECT Rol FROM usuarios WHERE = '$nombre'";
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
      while($reg=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($reg['Rol'] == "1") {
//Aquí va el código del menú con la opción "´Panel de control"
} else {
//Aquí va el código del menú sin la opción "Panel de control"
}}}
?>
```

Comment: El error que te genera es porque la query o esta mal o la variable `$nombre` no recibe nada. La funcion `isset()` "pregunta" si existe el valor de alguna variable. En tu caso, estas preguntando por si existe el valor de `$_COOKIE["MiGalleta"]`

Comment: Pon el código donde creas la cookie para ver como la estas creando.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el while por un foreach así nunca habrán elementos nulos en el loop

```html
<?php 
include ("conecta.php");
if (isset ($_COOKIE['MiGalleta'])){ 
    $nombre = $_COOKIE['MiGalleta'];
    $sql = "SELECT Rol FROM usuarios WHERE = '$nombre'";
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
      foreach($reg=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($reg['Rol'] == "1") {
//Aquí va el código del menú con la opción "´Panel de control"
} else {
//Aquí va el código del menú sin la opción "Panel de control"
}}}
?>
```